# Pause all processing Threads at then given point then resume them all and repeat the process until processing is done

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to print 1000 "Hello World" console lines equally split among 5 threads. Note that this is just pseudo requirement for simplicity. Actual work that I need will take more time than printing console lines.

What I want to achieve is to pause all 5 threads for 10 seconds when 250 lines in total by all threads are printed then to resume all threads and to repeat this process until all 1000 lines are printed. Is that possible?

So far I achieved the following:

```
public void produceLog() 
{
  int numThreads = 5; 
  int numTimesPerThread = 200; 
  int recordsPerPause = 250; 
  AtomicInteger totalLogsPrinted = new AtomicInteger(0);

  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

  for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
  {
    executorService.execute(new HelloWorldProducer(numThreads, numTimesPerThread, recordsPerPause, totalLogsPrinted));
  }

  try
  {
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e)
  {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    return "Error occurred: " + e.getMessage();
  }
}

static class HelloWorldProducer implements Runnable 
{
  private final int numThreads;
  private final int numTimes;
  private final int recordsPerPause;
  private final AtomicInteger totalLogsPrinted;

  HelloWorldProducer(int numThreads, int numTimes, int recordsPerPause, AtomicInteger totalLogsPrinted) 
  {
    this.numThreads = numThreads;
    this.numTimes = numTimes;
    this.recordsPerPause = recordsPerPause;
    this.totalRecords = totalRecords;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numTimes; i++) 
    {
      log.info("Hello World");
    }

    if (totalRecords.incrementAndGet() % recordsPerPause == 0 && totalRecords.get() != numTimes * numThreads) 
    {
      try 
      {
        log.info("Pausing thread {} for: 10 seconds", Thread.currentThread().getId());
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10000); // This will pause only this thread
        log.info("Continuing thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId());
      } 
      catch (InterruptedException e) 
      {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Aakash TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10000); will only pause 1 thread. 2nd thread will do totalRecords.incrementAndGet() and condition totalRecords.incrementAndGet() % recordsPerPause == 0 will be false therefore, printing will continue for 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th thread.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, your problem is, once thread one reaches total count of 249, it increments the atomic integer first, then get the value and use it. This makes the value to 250 and thread 1 goes to wait state.
Now, when thread 2 comes, it again **increments** the atomic integer first, which makes value to 251 and it fails the if condition.

Instead of using `incrementAndGet()` in your if condition, you can only get the value from `totalRecords`. If this condition satisfies, block the thread, else increment.

```
if (totalRecords.get() % recordsPerPause == 0 && totalRecords.get() != numTimes * numThreads) 
{
  try 
  {
    log.info("Pausing thread {} for: 10 seconds", Thread.currentThread().getId());
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10000); // This will pause only this thread
    totalRecords.incrementAndGet();
    log.info("Continuing thread {}", Thread.currentThread().getId());
  } 
  catch (InterruptedException e) 
  {
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
} else {
  totalRecords.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: When will this else block that does incrementAndGet be reached? Correct me if I am wrong but it looks to me that all threads will at some point have if condition satisfied and will pause each iteration forever.

Comment: Fair point. You can increment after sleep call.

Comment: @user1609 if this solves your problem, please accept as answer.